# SQL Count and Group By function

Tags: sql, group-by, count

What happens in the below code:

```
SELECT 
   A, 
   COUNT(A) AS A_Counts, 
   B, 
   COUNT(B) AS B_Counts
FROM Table
GROUP BY A,B ;
```

Can someone explain this piece of code

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, `COUNT(<expression>)` counts how many expressions evaluate to a value (not null).

In your case, it will count how many rows each group has, except for the groups where A or B are null (it will show zero in those cases).

For example, for the dataset:

```
A    B
---- ----
1    2
3    4
3    4
5    null
null 6
null null
```

null null

The result will be

```
A    B    count_a count_b
---- ---- ------- -------
1    1    1       1
3    4    2       2
5    null 1       0
null 6    0       1
null null 0       0
```

See for yourself at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R0VOuR1j).